# Very short decay: A bare quark?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, electroweak, hadronization

I keep reading the same phrase about the very short life time of the top quark:

> > Because the t-quark decays on a shorter than the characteristic QCD interaction-time it cannot hadronize. Therefore it give to possibility to be seen as a bare quark.

I cannot find any more information beyond this simple phrase. There are however a few things that I would like to seen cleared out (sorry for the naive questions) :

- The first question is simple: I don't understand why this offers to opportunity to see a bare quark, since this quark decays that fast it must be very difficult te see it...
- A bare quark?? I thought this was ruled to see colorful particles?

Comment: Do you know what the word "hadronize" means in this context?

Comment: Keep reading where?

Comment: You might find the comments under [a post where I relayed this tidbit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29162/520) useful.

Comment: Quark masses have an anomalous dimension and therefore its definition depends on the renormalization scheme and energy scale considered. Since the top does not hadronize, I think we can probe directly its pole mass. I guess that explains why it called a "bare quark", but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 3):

I too see this often, @QMechanic.

See, for example, Griffiths, Introduction to Elementary Particles, pg 47.

By this they mean that the time it would take for signals to cross the 'length' of a typical hardon is much longer than the time it takes for a top (truth!) quark to decay.

Since we assume cuasility, we cannot have an interaction which propagats faster than the limiting speed.